# Hibernate- OneToMany Relationship

Tags: hibernate

```
@Entity

@Table(name= "employee1100")

public class Employee {  

@Id

@Column(name="eid")

@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

private int id;  

@Column(name="ename")

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="employee",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)

private Set<Laptop> laptop;




@Entity

@Table(name="laptop1100")

public class Laptop {


    @Id

    @Column(name="laptop")

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

    private int id;

    @Column(name="lapdetails")

    private String details;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="empId")
    private Employee employee;




    Laptop lap1=new Laptop();
    Laptop lap2=new Laptop();

    lap1.setDetails("Lenovo");
    lap2.setDetails("HP");

    Employee e1=new Employee(); 

    lap1.setEmployee(e1);
    lap2.setEmployee(e1);

    Set<Laptop> laptop=new HashSet<Laptop>();

    laptop.add(lap1);
    laptop.add(lap2);

    e1.setName("Rahul"); 
    e1.setLaptop(laptop);


    session.save(e1);
```

I can see only one Laptop object inserted here respective to Employee record, Any issue?

Comment: Use List instead of set, and if you are planning to use set, make sure you over hashcode and equals method

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you use Set interface you should override the hashCode() and equals() methods. Have you tried List instead of Set interface?